# Why isn't the instance variable declared?

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, warnings

I'm using xcode 4.5.2 and LLVM 4.1. I am expecting that I do not need to synthesize a class property nor declare an instance variable, but I'm getting errors stating that these expectations are wrong.

My class:

```
@interface Test : NSManagedObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *string;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *number;
@end

@implementation Test
- (NSString*)string {
    return _string;
}
@end
```

1) **Use of undeclared identifier 'string'**

I've also seen in WWDC 2010 Session 144 the following:

```
return self->string;
```

But that is giving an error with a suggestion to use dot notation.

2) **Property 'string' found on object of type 'Test *'; did you mean to access it with the "." operator?**

I'm also getting a warning for `number`:

3) **Property 'number' requires method 'number' to be defined - use @synthesize, @dynamic or provide a method implementation in this class implementation**

I am entirely lost as to what is going on here. It's starting to boil my blood just a little bit. What am I missing?

Comment: Your example code above should work. I am trying your example with Xcode 4.5.2 and LLVM 4.1. It builds clean for me. No build issues here.

Comment: Also, I have intentionally used the technique displayed by your example code on many occasions. It is my understanding that this is supported behavior for late versions of LLVM.

Comment: The code I used is just example code. My actual code extends another class called `BaseModel` which extends `NSManagedObject`. When I change the `Test` class to extend `NSObject` it works like a charm as expected. So what is wrong with the way I'm extending the `BaseModel`?

Comment: Ah! Since you are subclassing `NSManagedObject`, I would say that complicates matters significantly. In that case, I would *strictly* stick to accessing properties with `self.foo` or `[self valueForKey:@"foo"]` notation. That would be much safer considering I don't think Apple makes any guarantees about how it declares its ivars in managed objects.

Comment: But if I used dot notation in an accessor method it would enter an infinite loop. The only solution I found is to manually `@synthesize number=_number` for my custom accessor properties.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple recommends that you *not* override property accessors and setters in your subclasses of `NSManagedObject`. That is where the CoreData magic lives. I think overriding those would be asking for trouble.

Comment: Apple docs on "Managed Object Accessor Methods" here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, dot notation is your friend!

Secondly, when you try to use `->` you must access the ivar. In the newest versions of Xcode and LLVM, an ivar with an underscore is created for you if you do not specify one yourself using `@synthesize`.

So you would do `self->_string`. You access the property when you use the `.` which is recommended. This also is probably why you're getting a warning on `number`, since `self->number` doesn't exist.

---

**Edit:** In response to the fact that you're using `NSManagedObject` I'd definitely recommend using properties (like Todd recommended). NSManagedObjects expect you to use `@dynamic` and since Core Data does a lot of stuff under the hood, Apple recommends you not change that.

If you want a custom getter/setter, I defer to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008138/334934) which uses the `primitive` methods:

```
- (NSString *)name
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *myName = [self primitiveName];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"name"];
    return myName;
}
```

And of course, [Apple Docs on the matter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1). And a [related question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510849/ios6-automatic-property-synthesize-not-working/12544653#12544653) that pertains to iOS 6.

Comment: All true except that the . operator is recommended, since they're different, may happen a situation when you need to use the -> operator. Also, his code should compile.

Comment: Note though that using the dot notation in a accessor method would cause an infinite loop. Also, when I do `self->_string` it says **'Test' does not have a member named '_string'**. So something is wrong here.

Comment: See my comment on my question. It seems the syntax does work, but not in my case the way I am extending another class. Trying to figure out why it's causing problems.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it now addresses the true cause of the issue. Please add this SO question as a reference to the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12544653/143225

Comment: MishieMoo, it is related in that it explains why `NSManagedObject` is different than `NSObject` when it comes to auto synthesized properties.

Answer (score 2):

If you implement both a setter and a getter method for a property, then the compiler assumes you're also taking care of the backing storage and will not create the `_string` instance variable for you.

You can either declare it yourself manually, or use `@synthesize string = _string;` force the compiler to declare it for you. The latter will give the ivar the right memory management semantics (strong, weak etc) based on the property type.

For managed objects, you need to implement MishieMoo's answer, but this is the cause of your NSObject subclass not having a _string variable as stated in the question.

It is covered in more detail [here](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html)

Comment: My Test object is actually a `NSManagedObject` and I've edited my question to reflect that as it's the root of my problems. Thanks for your additional info though.